# Plotting the value of a indicator range of data given the frequency

Tags: pine-script

As far as I'm able to code in pine, I was able to craft a code that allow me to answer this question:

"x% of the time the MACD is within +0.05 and -0.05"
This is how I did it:

```
a = ema(close,10)-ema(close,200)

var lowest = 0.00
if a<lowest
    lowest := a 

var highest = 0.00
if a>highest
    highest := a 

basis = max(-1*lowest,highest)
 
frequency(source,boundary) =>
    var r_count = 0.00
    var count = 0.00
    if source > boundary or source< -boundary
        count := count+1
    else 
        if source <boundary and source>-boundary
            r_count := r_count+1
    count/(count+r_count)
```

The problem is that I want to know the opposite, I need to find an answer to this question:
"60% (where 60% is just an example, I should be able to input any percentage I want) of the time MACD is within +x and -x range"

I tried using a for loop with no success, I'm not that expoert to find a solution to this. Hope someone can help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you are trying to get the % range from the median or the % range from zero (or the closest value to zero). Either way we can place all the values in an array so we can make use of `array.sort()`.

```
//@version=4
study("MACD range", overlay = false)

perc = input(60, title = "percentage of values")

a = ema(close,10)-ema(close,200)

var float[] macd_array = array.new_float()

array.unshift(macd_array, a) // put all macd values in an array

var label info_label = label.new(x = na, y = na, style = label.style_label_left)

if barstate.islast
    // If we need to find the range around the median
    n = array.size(macd_array)
    array.sort(macd_array) // sort values from lowest to highest
    median_index = round(n / 2) // the median
    
    median_first_index = median_index - round(perc / 2 / 100 * n)
    median_last_index = median_index + round(perc /2 / 100 * n)
    median_low_val = array.get(macd_array, median_first_index)
    median_high_val = array.get(macd_array, median_last_index)

    label_text = "Total number of values : " + tostring(n) + "\nFrom Median : \nFirst/Last Index : " + tostring(median_first_index) + " / " + tostring(median_last_index) + "\nRange from median : " + tostring(median_low_val) + " / " + tostring(median_high_val)
    
    
    // If we need the range around zero (or closest value to zero), we first need to find the index in the array of that zero value
    int zero_index = 0
    float zero_index_val = abs(array.get(macd_array, 0))
    for i = 1 to array.size(macd_array) - 1
        val = abs(array.get(macd_array, i))
        if val < zero_index_val
            zero_index_val := val
            zero_index := i

    int zero_first_index = na
    int zero_last_index = na
    int index_half_range = round(perc / 2 / 100 * n)
    
    // Once we have the index of zero, we need to check if the % of values exist equally above and below the zero
    
    // If all the values below zero are less than half needed values, we only need to get from the first index to the % of all values
    if zero_index - index_half_range < 0
        zero_first_index := 0
        zero_last_index := round(n * perc / 100)
    // Alternatively if the values above zero make up less than half the %
    else if zero_index + index_half_range > (array.size(macd_array) - 1) 
        zero_first_index := n - 1 - index_half_range * 2
        zero_last_index := n - 1
    // Otherwise we can go an equal half of the % of values above and below zero
    else
        zero_first_index := zero_index - index_half_range
        zero_last_index := zero_index + index_half_range
    
    zero_low_val = array.get(macd_array, zero_first_index)
    zero_high_val = array.get(macd_array, zero_last_index)
    
    label_text := label_text + "\n--------------------\n"
    label_text := label_text + "\nFrom zero basis"
    label_text := label_text + "\nFirst/Last Index : " + tostring(zero_first_index) + " / " + tostring(zero_last_index) + "\nRange from zero basis : " + tostring(zero_low_val) + " / " + tostring(zero_high_val)
    
    
    label.set_xy(info_label, x = bar_index, y = 0)
    label.set_text(info_label, text = label_text)
```

Comment: Hi, thank's very much. But I don't know if it's working properly. If I put the numbers your code gave as output (from zero basis) and then put them in my function I would expect to get as a result the input of your code, which is not the case.

Comment: https://www.tradingview.com/x/LA6ocOw2/ If I substitute actual macd into the code, it looks about right to me. What I've coded above will find the range of 60% of the values (+/- 30%) above/below zero. So it sorts all values in order. Finds zero, then the range values. So say you have 100 values, and let's say that after sorting the 50th value is zero. It finds the macd value of the 20th and 80th.

Comment: You also won't get quite the opposite result. The reason being that 60% of the values around zero won't have the same +/- actual range. The distribution will not be even. So the values below zero tend to be less dispersed / closer to zero and so it results in a smaller actual range than for the values above zero